# awk issue with printing the result

Tags: matlab, output, printf

Well the problem I am facing is very elementary. I have written the following code to divide a line into 10 parts and find the coordinates of each part. The program runs fine but the output text file is not showing correct result. I just want to print the result of the linspace in columns in a text file. Thanks.

```
h=input('enter the size of the test box ');
theta=input('the angle');
xs=input('enter the x1 position of the slipplane');
ys=input('enter the y1 position of the slipplane');

r=h/sind(theta);
xe=(xs+(h/sind(theta)));
ye=(ys+(h/sind(theta)));
x1=xs+4;
y1=ys+4;
x10=xe-4;
y10=ye-4;

   n=linspace(x1,x10,10)
   m=linspace(y1,y10,10)

fid = fopen('result.txt', 'wt'); 
fprintf(fid,' %f\t %f\n',n,m);
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: @kl3755 But the first five rows are repeating itself, dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
h=input('enter the size of the test box ');
theta=input('the angle');
xs=input('enter the x1 position of the slipplane');
ys=input('enter the y1 position of the slipplane');

r=h/sind(theta);
xe=(xs+(h/sind(theta)));
ye=(ys+(h/sind(theta)));
x1=xs+4;
y1=ys+4;
x10=xe-4;
y10=ye-4;

   n=linspace(x1,x10,10)
   m=linspace(y1,y10,10)

fid = fopen('result.txt', 'wt'); 
fprintf(fid,'%f\t %f\n',[n;m]);
fclose(fid);
```

terminal:

```
enter the size of the test box 10
the angle10
enter the x1 position of the slipplane10
enter the y1 position of the slipplane10

n =

  Columns 1 through 5

   14.0000   19.5097   25.0195   30.5292   36.0390

  Columns 6 through 10

   41.5487   47.0585   52.5682   58.0780   63.5877


m =

  Columns 1 through 5

   14.0000   19.5097   25.0195   30.5292   36.0390

  Columns 6 through 10

   41.5487   47.0585   52.5682   58.0780   63.5877
```

Content of result.txt:

```
14.000000    14.000000
19.509745    19.509745
25.019490    25.019490
30.529235    30.529235
36.038980    36.038980
41.548725    41.548725
47.058470    47.058470
52.568215    52.568215
58.077960    58.077960
63.587705    63.587705
```